# Issue with JavaScript API

Tags: javascript, html, api, audio, soundcloud

http://jsfiddle.net/bej28cts/
https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/guide#playing
So I'm following soundcloud's documentation to play a song, but I still can't get any music to play.

Here is a bare bones version of my app:

HTML:

```
<button onclick="start()">Click me</button>
```

JS:

```
SC.initialize({
    client_id: '44c88b31e709231ae8f61adc66908de3'
});

function start() {
    // stream track id 293
    SC.stream('/tracks/293').then(function (player) {
        player.play();
    });
}
```

I can't seem to hear any music. Any tips to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Code and your example works! I am using Edge.

EDIT: It's working in Internet Explorer and Firefox as well! Chrome does not play it and does not show any error.

Maybe you should the complete code from the documentation:

```
<script src="https://connect.soundcloud.com/sdk/sdk-3.0.0.js"></script>
<script>
SC.initialize({
  client_id: 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID',
  redirect_uri: 'http://example.com/callback'
});

// initiate auth popup
SC.connect().then(function() {
  return SC.get('/me');
}).then(function(me) {
  alert('Hello, ' + me.username);
});
</script>
```

Comment: Is edge a type of browser?

Comment: Yes, it's the successor to Internet Explorer.

Comment: That's really weird. It seems to be working on safari too. Why isn't it working on chrome?

Comment: There seems to be some problems with chrome and the flashplayer and soundcloud and... Try to disable flash in chrome to check that.